# strong measurability question

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, banach-spaces, operator-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space and $\mathcal L$ the collection of bounded linear operators on $X$. The strong operator topology has the sub-basis $\{B_{x,y,\epsilon}\colon x,y\in X,\epsilon>0\}$, where $B_{x,y,\epsilon}=\{T\colon \|Tx-y\|<\epsilon\}$. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by this topology is called the strongly measurable $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathcal L$.

Now the question (which has arisen in a study of the multiplicative ergodic theorem on Banach spaces):

> Let $K=\{T\in\mathcal L\colon \text{ker}(T)\ne\{0\}\}$. Is this set strongly measurable?

Thanks for any information.

Comment: Initial notes: (1) the unit ball $B$ of $\mathcal{L}$ with the strong operator topology is Polish; (2) it suffices to show $B \cap K$ is Borel in $B$; (3) the set $K$ is clearly analytic in $B$, so it would suffice to show it is coanalytic.

Comment: Thanks @NateEldredge: I switched operator algebras for descriptive set theory.

Comment: I thought about this for a while but didn't really get anywhere.  The only idea I had for coanalyticity was to try to characterize non-injective $T$ as $\forall S \: (ST \ne I)$, where $S$ ranges over some hopefully Polish space of unbounded closed operators - but I don't know what space that should be.  The formula $ST \ne I$ can be expressed as $\exists n \: (ST x_n \ne x_n)$ where $\{x_n\}$ is a countable dense subset of $X$, so it has a chance to be Borel.

Comment: Thanks @NateEldredge: my guess is that it is actually not measurable, but I am not well (at all) versed in Descriptive Set Theory. That said, I did make use of wikipedia and get to the point where I was able to understand what you had written.

Comment: I think the set is measurable if $X$ is a Hilbert space, but you probably know this already.

Comment: No. I don't know this. I'd like to see a proof or a reference if there is one.

Comment: I can answer this as deputy. Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space. Then for a contraction $T \in B(H)$ and polynomials $p_n(t):=(1-t)^n$, the sequence $(p_n(T^*T))_n$ monotonically converges in SOT to the orthogonal projection onto $\ker T$. Hence for a dense sequence $(v_m)_m$ in the unit ball of $H$, one has $\ker T = 0$ iff $\forall m$ $\exists n$ $\|p_n(T^*T)v_m\|<1/2$. Since each $p_n$ is SOT*-continuous in $T$ and SOT* and SOT measurabilities are the same, this proves SOT measurability of $\{ T:\ker T=0\}$. I don't know a reference nor the case for Banach spaces.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA: Thanks for this solution in the case of a separable Hilbert space. That's quite nice.

Comment: The following might be useful: By a [theorem of Kadets](http://testuvannya.com.ua/M.I.Kadets/PDF/K-1967-1.pdf), all separable Banach spaces are homeomorphic. Being an injection is certainly preserved by a homeomorphism, so maybe one can reduce to the separable Hilbert space case if one can relate the strong operator topology appropriately to the norm topology.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: So I believe (after scratching my head for a while/having it explained to me by my grad student) that the homeomorphism that Kadets produces isn't linear. This is quite bad, as a linear operator on $X$ would then be conjugate to a non-linear operator on $H$.

Comment: One can do it when $X$ is separable and reflexive (or more generally when $X$ is a separable dual space and $T$ is weak*-continuous). For a dense sequence $(x_m)_m$ in the unit ball of $X$, one has $\ker T \neq 0$ iff $\exists m$ $\forall K$ $\exists n$ such that $\| x_m - x_n \| < \| x_m \|/2$ and $\| T x_n \| < 1/K$.

Comment: Thanks you very much, @NarutakaOZAWA. I wonder: would it be possible to write this as an answer (and maybe could you explain why your condition is sufficient for a non-trivial kernel?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is true at least when $X$ is a separable and reflexive. Take a dense sequence $(x_n)_n$ in the unit sphere of $X$. Then, for any $T \in B(X)$, one has $\ker T \neq 0$ iff $\exists m$ $\forall k$ $\exists n$ such that $\| x_m - x_n \| < 1/2$ and $\| Tx_n \| < 1/k$. Indeed, since the closed unit ball of $X$ is weakly compact and any $T \in B(X)$ is weak-weak continuous, if the latter condition holds, then any weak limit point $x$ of the subsequence $(x_{n(k)})_k$ satisfies $\| x \| \geq \| x_m \| - \| x_m - x \| \geq 1/2$ and $Tx = 0$. This proves the "if" direction. The "only if" direction is easy.