# Measurability of a generalized point spectrum

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Assume that  $ T:H\oplus H\rightarrow H\oplus H$ is a unitary linear operator on the double sum of a separable Hilbert space $H$ with itself.

Let us call a pair $(\lambda, \mu)\in\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}$ to be a point of the generalized point spectrum $\sigma(T)$ if and only if there exists a vector $(x,y)\neq (0,0)\in H\oplus H$, such that $T(x,y)=(\lambda x, \mu y)$.

Question: Is it true that $\sigma(T)$ is a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: @paul, I can not immediately give your a counterexample, but I do not see why it should be closed... It is a generalization of a point spectrum and not of a spectrum..

Comment: It's Borel. $(\lambda,\mu)\in\sigma(T)$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\ker(T-\mathrm{diag}(\lambda,\mu))\neq\{0\}$. The latter is strongly measurable, see  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272128/strong-measurability-question

Comment: @Narutaka OZAWA Thanks!